# How does make continue compilation?

Tags: linux, compiling, make, interrupt, compiler

I know that I can interrupt a `make` process anytime without having to recompile the entire source tree again. As I know, `make` only compiles a target if it's not compiled yet, or the source code is modified after the last compilation.
But if I interrupt `make`, there will surely be one or more (depending on the concurrency level) half-ready binaries. What does it do with them the next time I run `make`? Or does it finish the current target when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to avoid partly compiled binaries?

Comment: Mostly you only need to worry if the computer powered off unexpectedly. A few times my Ubuntu managed to get in a kernel deadlock (or whatever it is) and left half-ready binaries, which ended up wasting more than two hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In simple terms, you can think of `make` as having a (possibly large) number of steps, where each step takes a number of files as input and creates one file as output.

A step might be "compile `file.c` to `file.o`" or "use `ld` to link `main.o` and `file.o` into `program`". If you interrupt `make` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, then the currently executing step will be terminated which will (or should) remove the output file it was working on. There are usually not any "half-ready binaries" left behind.

When you restart `make`, it will look at the timestamps of all the input and output files and rerun the steps where:

- an input file has a newer timestamp than the output file
- the output file does not exist

This generally means that if a step takes a long time to run (it's rare on modern computers, but the `ld` step for large programs could easily take many minutes when `make` was designed), then stopping and restarting `make` will start that step over from the beginning.

The reality of your average `Makefile` is considerably more complicated than the above description, but the fundamentals are the same.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> causes a `SIGINT` to be sent to the process running. This signal can be caught by the process. In the make source code you can find a trap for this signal in `commands.c`:

```
  /* If we got a signal that means the user
     wanted to kill make, remove pending targets.  */

  if (sig == SIGTERM || sig == SIGINT

  ... remove childrens ...

  /* Delete any non-precious intermediate files that were made.  */

  remove_intermediates (1);
```

`remove_intermediates()` is the cleanup function of `make`, see it's definition here:

```
/* Remove all nonprecious intermediate files.
   If SIG is nonzero, this was caused by a fatal signal,
   meaning that a different message will be printed, and
   the message will go to stderr rather than stdout.  */
```

And later in the function you see, they will be effectively deleted:

```
status = unlink (f->name);
```

**Conclusion:**
Generally don't be affraid of interrupting a compilation with `make`. If it's not an uncatchable signal (`SIGKILL, SIGSEGV, SIGSTOP`) it will do a cleanup of intermediate files.

Comment: `SIGSEGV` is catchable on many Unices.

Answer (score 1):

When something stops `make` (be it ctrl-C, shutdown, or even a command that fails), the work already done stays. When restated, `make` does as always: it figures out what still needs to be done (because a file changed or `make` never got to have it processed doesn't matter) and goes on with the job.

The above description clearly presumes the relevant `Makefile`s describe the dependencies and commands to execute correctly, so all what needs to be (re)made is.